# $x y''+y'+y=0$ How to approach

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

the problem is
$x y''+y'+y=0$

the result is :
$c_1 J_0\left(2 \sqrt{x}\right)+2 c_2 Y_0\left(2 \sqrt{x}\right)$

I tried to substitute a few functions to try but other than that I have no idea.

Comment: This looks like it's a problem where you'd seek a power series solution.

Comment: And then try to recognize the resulting series?

Comment: this is an Emden Fauler equation

Comment: Try to use Laplace Transform to get the solution.

Comment: Typically with power series solutions one doesn't expect to recognize the series, and in your specific case you wouldn't unless you were especially cognizant of Bessel functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\frac{dy}{dx}+y=0$$
Let $x=\frac{X^2}{4}$ then  $dx=\frac{1}{2}X dX$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dX}\frac{dX}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dX}\frac{2}{X}$$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{\frac{dy}{dX}\frac{2}{X}}{dX}\frac{dX}{dx}=\left(\frac{d^2y}{dX^2}\frac{2}{X}-\frac{2}{X^2}\frac{dy}{dX}\right)\frac{2}{X}$$
$$x\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\frac{dy}{dx}+y=\frac{X^2}{4}\left(\frac{d^2y}{dX^2}\frac{2}{X}-\frac{2}{X^2}\frac{dy}{dX}\right)\frac{2}{X}+\frac{dy}{dX}\frac{2}{X}+y=0$$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dX^2}+\frac{1}{X}\frac{dy}{dX}+y=0$$
This is the Bessel ODE on the standard form, which known solution is :
$$y=c_1J_0(X)+c_2Y_0(X)$$
$X=2\sqrt x$
$$y=c_1J_0(2\sqrt x)+c_2Y_0(2\sqrt x)$$
Note :

In case of $x<0$, the relationship between Bessel functions and modified Bessel fonctions leads to :
$$y=C_1I_0(2\sqrt{-x})+C_2K_0(2\sqrt{-x})$$

Comment: Given the result, I agree that this is the way to go, but how does one come up with the substitution $x=X^2/4$ in the first place _not_ knowing the solution?

Comment: There is a general method when an ODE of Bessel kind is encountered on a non standard form : Let $y(x)=x^a f(b x^c)$ The calculus is boring. This leads to a form of ODE where, at the end, obvious simplifications appear in order to obtain the standard form of Bessel ODE. Those simplifications determine the parameters $a, b,c$. In the present case, the values $a=0$, $b=2$ and $c=\frac{1}{2}$ are obtained.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think your explanation for the substitution should be a part of the answer, it is the most crucial point in my opinion.

Comment: I agree : the substitution should be a part of the answer. But I mentioned : "The calculus is boring". It would be even more boring to type it. That is why I don't type it.